Bad girls get a surprise ending
OK, I know that as soon as I submit this, I'm going to remember the name of an actress, and that will be enough info for me to figure out the name of the movie. But that won't happen until AFTER I hit "Post Your Question", so here goes: 
I don't know when it was made, but it aired somewhat frequently back in the late 70's / early 80's, when there were only three movie channels (at least in my neighborhood) and they were obviously desperate for content. 
The plot of this one was: a family guy is home alone and somehow winds up with two young female visitors. Things quickly escalate from "I can't do this" to "hopefully I won't get caught" to "I'm screwed, because these two girls are definitely insane, and probably homicidal." Most of the nudity is a tease to keep you thinking that eventually there will be more, and most of the violence is cartoonish. but what is unforgettable is the end, when the two girls leave the house and skip away -- yes, literally skip -- and in the last seconds of the movie they are run over by a van.
As I recall, the actresses weren't unknowns, which is why I know that as soon as I post this I'll remember at least one of their names. Just because.

I knew I'd remember. It was Death Game, starring Sondra Locke, whose name I can never remember because it's hard to think of her as anything besides "Clint Eastwood's former girlfriend who got a lot of roles for that reason." I even found the full movie on youtube; here's the unforgettable ending: 


